# updated design Token available warnings and css styles are not applying to my component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, css, slds

I have a `Block.cmp` file and custom CSS settings are not applying in the result.

`Block.cmp` file code:

```
<div class="board-block slds-align_absolute-center slds-var-m-around_medium slds-var-p-around_medium" onclick="{!c.blockClickHandler}">
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.open}">
        <div>{!v.label}</div>
    </aura:if>
</div>
```

`Block.css` code:

```
.THIS.board-block{
    background-color: white;
    height: 80px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 4px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: large;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 10%), 0 1px 2px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 6%);
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.THIS.board-block:hover {
    background-color: #ededed;
    border: 1px solid #ededed;
}
```

Comment: is it a full markup of your component? can you please provide the entire component starting with `aura:component` ?

Comment: this is not full markup. I just provided the markup where I have applied styles. I am able solve this issue by just deleting my component  from the page and adding again to the page. Thank you for the response.